# get temp file name in server machine folder in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to get the temp file name in my server machine temp folder. For example:

```
string TempFile = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();
```

but instead of using System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName() I need to use Environment. How can I accomplish that? Thanks

Comment: GetTempFileName function can receive path as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Look with class `Environment` [Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP")](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.environment(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: This gives me the temporary directory but how do I get the file in that directory?